# How to identify missing document IDs in two Elasticsearch indices, "demo-cm" and "demo-v2," that share the same document structure?

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, postman, elastic-stack

**demo-v2 has below doc -**

```
[{
    "_index": "demo-v2",
    "_type": "v2",
    "_id": "1",
    "_source": {
            "user": "kimchy",
        "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
    }
},{
    "_index": "demo-v2",
    "_type": "v2",
    "_id": "2",
    "_source": {
        "user": "kimchy",
        "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
    }
},{
    "_index": "demo-v2",
    "_type": "v2",
    "_id": "3",
    "_source": {
        "user": "kimchy",
        "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
    }
}]
```

**demo-cm has below doc -**

```
[{
    "_index": "demo-cm",
    "_type": "cm",
    "_id": "1",
    "_source": {
        "user": "kimchy",
        "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
    }
}]
```

**Output should me **

```
ids = ["2", "3"]
```

I've made several attempts with Painless scripting, but I'm struggling to obtain the precise solution. Can anyone provide guidance or an example for my scenario?

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "missing_ids": {
      "scripted_metric": {
        "init_script": "state.docs = []",
        "map_script": "state.docs.add(doc._id.value)",
        "combine_script": "return state.docs",
        "reduce_script": "def unique_ids = []; def uniques = []; for (docs in states) {  unique_ids.addAll(docs); }  return unique_ids;"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `_id` field is not contained in the doc so you cannot access it that way

Comment: Also your current logic would return ALL ids, not only the diff between the two indexes

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Is it possible to get only unique ids using the script?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have your ids also stored in the document, for instance in the `id` field.

Comment: This is the exact doc I am having, 
{
 "_index": "replica-demo-nikks1-cm",
 "_type": "cm",
 "_id": "095a42aa6b2e464cb8ffa7c0814d14d2",
 "_version": 1,
 "_seq_no": 0,
 "_primary_term": 1,
 "found": true,
 "_source": {
  "AccountName": "demo",
 }
}

Comment: In the script you can only access what's in the document, i.e. what you see in `_source` so you'll first need to run `_update_by_query` in order to add the `_id` value inside the document

Comment: Yeah, I got you. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Let me know if that's an option for you, and I'll provide the right logic for doing it. Also can you tell how many documents are in those two indexes, because running such scripts on a big volume of documents is not recommended.

Comment: The document count is near about 2 million. And I can't update the id in _source.

Comment: Ok, then scripted_metric is not going to help you, unfortunately